# Trying to adjust the output of PHP echo

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm trying to display results side by side rather than this:

[image: actual result]

And this is the what I'm trying to create (result to show side by side):

[image: trying to create]

This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM house ORDER by id ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['header'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $link .= "<a href='#'>".$title."</a>";

        echo "<div class='cat_link'>";
        echo $link;
        echo '<dt></strong></dt><dd>'
            . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' 
            . base64_encode($img) . '" width="200" height="200">'
            . '</dd>';
        echo $description;
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<p> There are are no house</p>";
}
?>
```

Is there a way to do it?

i also tried float:left but the whole thing turns like this
[image]

edit: ok after the help from you guys this is my final result and these are my codes hope it will helps you at some point

php code

```
<main class="content">
    <?php
    include_once("connect.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM house ORDER by id ASC";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['header'];
            $img = $row['img'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $address = $row['address'];
            $link .= "<a href='#'>".$title."</a>";
            
        echo "<div class='cat_link'>";
        echo "<a href='#'>".$title."</a>";
        echo '<dd>'
     . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($img) . '" width="200" height="200">'
     . '</dd>';
        echo $description;
        echo "</div>";
            
        }
        
    }
    else {
        echo "<p> There are are no house</p>";
    }
    ?>
    </main>
```

CSS code

```
.cat_link{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #000000;
}

.cat_link:hover{
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.content {
    background: black;
    margin-top: -5px; /* this is my margin so your could be vary or remove it if you dont want it */
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

results
[image]

tada :)

Comment: `<dt></strong></dt><dd>` isn't valid html markup

Comment: on thats there for me to add my own text for the picture. tbh i dont need it i just forgot to remove it

Comment: also, please consider reading [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a CSS issue and not a PHP issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy! Just add this to your cat_link class in css: `display: inline-block`
Take a look at this for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/x6tmatvc/

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: wow!! nice its works now i just need to make the height size fixed because the results have different height :) ty

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your  in `<li>` and set a class in css with the attribute: float: left;

like this:

```
    echo '<li class="float-left">';
    echo "<div class='cat_link'>";
    echo $link;
    echo '<dt></strong></dt><dd>'
        . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' 
        . base64_encode($img) . '" width="200" height="200">'
        . '</dd>';
    echo $description;
    echo "</div>";
    echo '</li>';
```

CSS:

```
.float-left{
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: its works on making it to go left but my div and navigation bar collapse